# Can I use FetchXML to retrieve an entity by guid when object type not known?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I have an error log file that contains a GUID of an Entity in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365 Online, but I do not know the Entity's object type. Is there a way of using FetchXML (or otherwise) to retrieve any Entity with the matching GUID regardless of object type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is to retrieve the metadata of all entities (using the `RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest` message) and after to an `IOrganizationService.Retrieve` to check if the record exits or not.

You can find a complete example in this blog post:

[Retrieve Entity Logical Name from a record GUID](https://www.crmanswers.net/2013/04/retrieve-entity-logical-name-from.html)

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, we should always pass the target entity name for the fetchxml or any query in CRM.

But if you're looking for a way to get the entity name ([followup to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58199315/7920473)), when you have the GUID in message block/exception details - you can get the "Primary Entity" from the same plugin trace log record as well.

[image]

[Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2016/07/05/debugging-your-plug-ins-with-the-plug-in-trace-log/)